# Custom New Page for DocumentSet-Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

I want to create custom new page for document set in Sharepoint online. I dont want to modify master page or NewDocSet.aspx. I created new page in designer and assigned it as default page in content type.

Answer (score 0):

After you did your steps, did you meet an error?

There is a Github article which give the steps about creating custom document set in SharePoint Online, you can refer to [it](https://gist.github.com/Oceanswave/e0cd45e2083e51c5026117dc74d65d41).